# Fixing R and shiny package together

Tags: r, shiny

I created this simple text prediction model . How do I integrate my main code with Shiny app I created ? How to create an output based from R code I created with shiny app

```
    library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(tm)
library(markovchain)



sherlock <- readLines('war.txt')



# Get chapter title
#chapter_title <- sherlock %>% 
  #filter(text != " ") %>% 
  #slice(c(4:15)) %>% 
  #pull(text) %>% 
  #tolower() %>% 
  #str_trim()


text_sherlock <- sherlock %>% 
  strsplit(" ") %>% 
  unlist() 

text_sherlock %>% head(30)

fit_markov <- markovchainFit(text_sherlock)

for (i in 1:10) {
  
  set.seed(i)
  
  markovchainSequence(n = 5, 
                      markovchain = fit_markov$estimate,
                      t0 = " ", include.t0 = T) %>% 
    
    # joint words
    paste(collapse = " ") %>% 
    
    # create proper sentence form
    str_replace_all(pattern = " ,", replacement = ",") %>% 
    str_replace_all(pattern = " [.]", replacement = ".") %>% 
    str_replace_all(pattern = " [!]", replacement = "!") %>% 
    
    str_to_sentence() %>% 
    
    print()
}

ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Shiny application to predict the next word"),
  
  fluidRow(HTML(" <strong>Author: x </strong>") ),
  fluidRow(HTML(" <strong>Date: 06-29-2020</strong>") ),
  
  fluidRow(
    br(),
    p("This Shiny application acts as text predictior app ")),
  br(),
  br(),
  
  fluidRow(HTML("<strong>Enter a word. Press \"Next words\" button to predict the following words</strong>") ),
  fluidRow( p("\n") ),
  
  # Sidebar layout
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("inputString", "Enter a word here",value = " "),
      submitButton("Next words")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      h4("Predicted Next Word"),
      verbatimTextOutput("prediction"),
      textOutput('text1'),
      textOutput('text2')
    )
  )
))




shinyApp(ui,server)
```

T0 in markovchain sequence is the place where the word entered in Shiny app should go into and give the output
Example

```
 markovchainSequence(n = 5, 
                      markovchain = fit_markov$estimate,
                      t0 = "prince", include.t0 = T)
```

> gave me the output as :
>
> ```
> [1] "Prince answered pierre, asked pierre, looked"
> [1] "Prince and stamped her father dismissed"
> [1] "Prince and converse in a momentary"
> [1] "Prince bowed and looking at four."
> [1] "Prince and fussily in a low"
> [1] "Prince bowed again turning to justify.”"
> [1] "Prince was an inquiring look at"
> [1] "Prince with a cousin of a"
> [1] "Prince and the last deciding seriously"
> [1] "Prince with the very nice, very"
> ```

```
the above output should come up in the final shiny output
```

Comment: (1) *"How to integrate ... with my shiny app?"* Write it as a *function* that returns the value(s) you need. (2) Don't use `print` as the last thing in a function; printing to the console might be nice for the user to *see*, but programmatically it is close to useless. This might mean you need to iteratively append to a `list` or perhaps use `lapply` or `sapply` to replace your `for` loop.

Comment: but without the print() function,it does not give any sentences output back to me

Comment: You're missing the point of functional programming, where the function either implicitly or explicitly `return`s a value, a vector, a `list`, or some kind of object. `print` *may* return the object sent to it (depending on which S3 `print` method it is), but in this case I think your function should return something, not just tell you that something was found/generated, and make you copy stuff from the console, parse out the `[1]` R vector index helper, and use elsewhere.

Comment: BTW: you can replace your three `str_replace_all` with a single: `str_replace_all(pattern = " ([!,.])", replacement = "\\1")`.

Comment: `for` loops don't return anything, so your comment above is technically correct. However, before the `for` loop, try `vec <- c()`, and instead of printing it, append it with `x <- markovchainSequence(...) %>% paste(...) %>% str_replace_all(...) %>% str_to_sentence(); vec <- c(vec, x)`, and then after your `for` loop you have a vector `vec` with all 10 sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will be incomplete, for two reasons: (1) I don't have those packages, so I'll focus on functionization of your process and one shiny server component that will use that, and (2) I don't know what other functionality you have in your shiny, so I don't know how best to incorporate it into that structure.

```r
library(tidyverse)   # dplyr, stringr
library(tidytext)    # ?
library(tm)          # ?
library(markovchain) # markov* funcs
library(shiny)

# global section, available to both ui/server
sherlock <- readLines('war.txt')
text_sherlock <- unlist(strsplit(sherlock, " "))
fit_markov <- markovchainFit(text_sherlock)

make_sentences <- function(word, n = 10, use.seed = FALSE) {
  sapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
    if (use.seed) set.seed(i)
    markovchainSequence(n = 5, 
                        markovchain = fit_markov$estimate,
                        t0 = word, include.t0 = TRUE) %>% 
      # joint words
      paste(collapse = " ") %>% 
      # create proper sentence form
      str_replace_all(pattern = " ([!,.])", replacement = "\\1") %>%
      str_to_sentence()
  })
}

# ui component (no changes here)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage( ... ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sentences <- reactive({
    make_sentences(input$inputString)
  })
  output$prediction <- renderText({ sentences() })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I don't know what intentions you have for `input$text1` and 2, and I'm assuming a bunch in my use if `input$inputString`. Hope I guess correctly.

I chose to separate the sentence generator into its own reactive data because often (typically?) there is another HTML component that might use those sentences for something, such as to count them, to look for some other 'meta' within them, who knows. Generally in `shiny` apps, I like to keep the actual rendering as simple as possible: a single call to `table`, a single `plot`, etc ... but no generation of data within them if possible. Sharing data between reactive components is a very useful feature.

Comment: Getting this Error -Warning: Error in markovchainSequence: Error! Initial state not defined
  [No stack trace available]    ----- Also on Shiny interface - "Predicted Next Word"
  Error! Initial state not defined

Comment: my bad . words are case sensitive as I did not normalize making all text in lower case

Comment: yeah, that kind of warning/error is "covered" in my first statement: *"I don't have those packages"*, implying that I've done no error-checking for function calls, etc. I'm hoping that the "structure" of this answer gives you what you need, even if it doesn't perfectly handle all of the ancillary things (like using the `markovchain` package, with which I have no experience). Sorry, this is what I have for you, hope it can help.

Comment: works totally just like I wanted as I am new to Shiny . just need to polish the display of output

Comment: If this sufficiently answers your question, please accept it. Thank you!